# How to modify iptables so a port is accessible on the server

Tags: centos, iptables, port

when I do

```
curl --insecure https://localhost/svn
```

from my linux box I can see that it is returning some data

However, when I run curl on this machine from another machine on the same network e.g.

```
curl --insecure https://<serverip>/svn
```

I get an error `curl: (7) couldn't connect to host`

Even though I can run other things like `curl http://<serverip>:8080/` or `curl http://<serverip>:9090/`

Is there something I can do with iptables to make this work or something else?

Here is what my iptables looks like:

```
# iptables -L -n --line-numbers
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination         
1    ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state RELATED,ESTABLISHED 
2    ACCEPT     icmp --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
3    ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
4    ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state NEW tcp dpt:22 
5    ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state NEW tcp dpt:8080 /* Tomcat Server port */ 
6    ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state NEW tcp dpt:9090 /* Tomcat Server port */ 
7    REJECT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           reject-with icmp-host-prohibited 

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination         
1    REJECT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           reject-with icmp-host-prohibited 

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination
```

Comment: If you keep deleting your questions you'll end up being auto banned.

Answer (score 1):

Open port 443 which is the default for https

```
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
```

Note -I is important. If that works use

```
service iptables save
```

to update `/etc/sysconfig/iptables`.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes selinux may block curl requests. You should check your selinux configuration that it is in permissive mode or disabled.